# How to add files into a directory of github repository through git command?

Tags: git

Suppose I've a github repository and inside that repository I've a directory/folder and I want to add a file through git command into the directory/folder( which is inside the repository). Thank you...

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/using-git/about-git#example-contribute-to-an-existing-repository

Answer (score 1):

This question is very beginner and I do not think it is appropriate. But in order not to leave the question unanswered:

1. You can refer to the [Git](https://git-scm.com/) documents.
   ۲. Watch video courses on platforms like [Udemy](https://udemy.com).